# Help with 500 - Internal Server Error (even with no AMPscript)

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm trying to create a basic sign up/log in page using an HTML block. I found this code on Code Pen i really liked (https://codepen.io/colorlib/pen/aaaoVJ) so I copied and pasted it as a cloud page to use for testing purposes.

However, even though I published the page and it has ZERO AMPscript in it right now. I keep getting a 500 - Internal Server Error page.

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong here? I'm pasting the HTML code below, the only difference between this and the code on CodePen is that I removed the Javascript and updated the URL for the CSS

```
<!-- Custom Theme files --> <link href="https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/utyfntsrc4u" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"> <!-- //Custom Theme files --> <!-- web font --> <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- //web font -->


 <!-- main -->  <div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">   <h1>Creative SignUp Form</h1>   <div class="main-agileinfo">    <div class="agileits-top">
    <form action="#" method="post">
     <input class="text" type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="">
     <input class="text email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
     <input class="text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
     <input class="text w3lpass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="">
     <div class="wthree-text">
      <label class="anim">
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required="">
       <span>I Agree To The Terms & Conditions</span>
      </label>
      <div class="clear"> </div>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="SIGNUP">
    </form>
    <p>Don't have an Account? <a href="#"> Login Now!</a></p>    </div>   </div>   <!-- copyright -->   <div class="colorlibcopy-agile">    <p>© 2018 Colorlib Signup Form. All rights reserved | Design by <a href="https://colorlib.com/" target="_blank">Colorlib</a></p>   </div>   <!-- //copyright -->   <ul class="colorlib-bubbles">    <li></li>    <li></li>    <li></li>    <li></li>    <li></li>    <li></li>    <li></li>    <li></li>    <li></li>    <li></li>   </ul>  </div>  <!-- //main -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue...I was leveraging the HTML block instead of going into "Code View" and modifying the HTML directly there.